# LogicApp And Github Integration (ARM Template)

Tags: azure, github, azure-logic-apps, cicd, azure-logic-app-standard

I recently was looking at Azure logic apps and wanted implement the CICD process. I was successful in getting the template and use it for ARM deployment but what I am looking forward for is a way to store the arm template into GitHub (for my dev logic app) and use it to promote to higher environment , just like how Azure data factory does [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control)

Unfortunately I couldn’t find a way to intergrade Logicapp and GitHub , Can we do that ?

This [Link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-azure-resource-manager-templates.md) describes how to generate it but nothing on integration to GitHub in an automated fashion.

Any info is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First prepare an ARM template of your Logic App. Please see an example [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-resource-manager-templates-overview). Then you can automate logic app deployment using GitHub Actions tasks. To do so, you can use task called "Deploy Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Template. Check [task's documentation](https://github.com/Azure/arm-deploy) for 'how tos" examples.

[image]

Comment: I understand that we can do it once the ARM template is generated and that is exactly how i did automate it using Azure Devops. The question is , if your logic apps are prone to frequent changes and it has to be promoted from dev >> qa >> prod ,  how do we do it ? . A very similar case is for Azure Data factory which allows automated Arm template generation into GITHUB. If the logicapp is not prone to changes i agree  , i can set it up once and leave it. The Links that i posted above contains ways to generate arm using powershell ,vscode etc but not with git integration .

Answer (score -1):

There is a visual studio code extension for logic apps which allows for the git repo integration.  From their you can run your pipeline for code promotion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: what extension? Can you be more specific?